# Fabric 2.5, how to skip a host if it is unavailable?

Tags: python, fabric, python-fabric-2

I use Fabric **2.5** and have not many servers (10-20), at any time, everyone can become inaccessible, this is normal behavior. How I can check the connection or skip a bad host?

In Fabric **1.4** we can use `--skip-bad-hosts` (and `env.skip_bad_hosts`) to bypass problematic hosts, but this functional now [not](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1809) [porting](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/sites/www/upgrading.rst) in Fabric **2.5**.

I haven’t done anything on this wonderful framework before, maybe I'm doing something wrong?
My `fabfile.py`:

```
import os

from fabric.connection import Connection
from fabric.tasks import task
from fabric.config import Config

USERNAME = os.getenv('USERNAME')
PASSWORD = os.getenv('PASSWORD')

def get_instance_ips():
    return ['10.10.10.10', '10.10.10.11', '10.10.10.12', '10.10.10.12', ... ]

def get_hosts():
    ips = sorted(get_instance_ips())
    return [{
        "host": f"{USERNAME}@{ip}",
        "connect_kwargs": {"password": PASSWORD},
    } for ip in ips]

@task
def firstTask(c):
    print("CONNECTION....")
    for index, host in enumerate(get_hosts()):
      print(f"****** Run in host {index} at {host['host']} ******")
      remote = Connection(**host)
      remote.run('some action')
```

Now if any of the addresses is unavailable, I get an error:

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 349, in <lambda>
  retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  socket.timeout: timed out
```

I can return to version Fabric **1.4**, but I would like to use Fabric **2.5**, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but we can use a try/except for the connection

```
hosts = ["admin@web1", "admin@web2"]
for host in hosts:
    try:
        conn = Connection(host)
        some_function(conn)
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR: ", e)
```